# Splitting data from a CSV file based on index values of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am working with a CSV file that contains features extracted from 3 types of signals (Bluetooth, WiFi and Drone). I would like to save 3 separate data frames, each including the features of only one of the signal types.

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vmatei2/Drone_detection/master/Features.csv'
names = ['I_std','I_mean','I_mad','Q_std', 'Q_mean' ,'Q_mad','I_kurtosis','Q_kurtosis','Signal_type']
data = pd.read_csv(url, names = names)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `groupby`

```
gp = data.groupby('Signal_type').groups
bt_data = data.iloc[gp['BT']] 
wifi_data = data.iloc[gp['WIFI']]
drone_data = data.iloc[gp['Drone']]
```

Or like this:

```
wifi_data = data[data['Signal_type'] == 'WIFI']
```